# Software for computing dimension groups?

Tags: group-theory, coding-theory, math-software, k-theory

Given an $n\times n$ integer-valued matrix $A$, one can define the stationary direct limit

$$\varinjlim (\mathbb{Z}^n,A)=\mathbb{Z}^n\overset{A}{\to}\mathbb{Z}^n\overset{A}{\to}\mathbb{Z}^n\overset{A}{\to}\cdots.$$

One can interpret $A$ as the adjacency matrix of a graph $G$ and then this computation yields the so-called (stable) dimension group of the edge shift (subshift of finite type) associated with $G$.

Does anyone know of a software for computing these gadgets? More generally, any reference on how to compute these groups in many situations would be appreciated.

Edit: $A$ can be taken such that every entry is nonnegative, if that helps.

Comment: That limit is in general an uncountable abelian group. What exactly do you mean by "compute it"?

Comment: Isn't it a countable union? You are right in that "compute it" is somewhat vague. I guess I want to find a nice presentation, at least in "good" cases and when $n$ is small for example. For instance, if $n=1$ and $A=2$ this is the group of dyadic rationals, which is described as $\mathbb{Z}[1/2]$.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez: the limit is a quotient of the sum $\Bbb{Z}^n \oplus \Bbb{Z}^{n} \oplus \ldots$ and hence is countable. So it certainly makes sense to ask whether there is software to help compute in it.

Comment: How do you interpret an integer valued matrix as an adjacency matrix? the familiar adjacency matrix is binary (0 and 1 entries).

Comment: I allow multiple edges between vertices and loops, of course I won't get negative numbers. The matrix need not be symmetric since edges have a direction.

Comment: can you describe how get the admissible sequences from A?

Comment: Is there a relation to coding theory? I fail to see one ([tag:coding-theory] has nothing to do with the process of producing software).

Comment: Jyrki Lahtonen: Take a look at "Symbolic dynamics and coding" by Lind and Marcus.

Comment: unknown: Just look at bi-infinite paths on the graph whose adjacency matrix is $A$.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. ${}{}$